# Parsing through email in Ruby using Action Mailer

Tags: ruby, email, parsing, action, mailer

I retrieve mail using net/pop , but I also need to parse through the email to obtain subject,from address and email body.
Any ideas with Action Mailer? 
I'm supposed to use 3rd party gems.(No,not even Tmail)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/pop'
require 'pop_ssl'

Net::POP3.enable_ssl(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)  

def pull_mail
  Net::POP3.start("pop.gmail.com", 995, "uname","pass") do |pop|  

    if pop.mails.empty?  
      puts 'No mails.'  
    else  
      pop.each_mail do |mail|  
      puts mail_header
    end  
  end

end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to write your email handler, and all the parsing will be done for you behind the scenes:

```
class MailHandler < ActionMailer::Base
  def receive(email)
    # here you will have an email object and will be able to call methods like
    # email.subject and email.attachments

    puts "from: #{email.from}, subject: '#{email.subject}'"
  end
end
```

When you get emails using Net::POP3, just hand them off to your handler:

```
Net::POP3.start(server, port, username, password) do |pop|
  pop.each_mail { |mail| MailHandler.receive(mail.pop) }
end
```